# Am I not using the setter method correctly?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

So I have to make a program that allows a user to "check-out" books and periodicals from a library, using classes and inheritance between the classes. There is a main class named *LibraryItems* with the subclasses *Book* and *Periodical.* I will provide an example of the issue that I am having:

This is the Book subclass:

```
class Book(LibraryItem):
    def __init__(self, call_num):
        LibraryItem.__init__(self, call_num)
        self.__book_list = None

    def set_book_list(self, lis):
        self.__book_list = lis

    def get_book_list(self):
        return self.__book_list
```

And here is a method from the *Controller* class that reads text from an input file and stores it in a list, it is used by the main() method to run the program:

```
def read_input(self, filename):
    book = Book(LibraryItem)
    period = Periodical(LibraryItem)
    bl = []
    pl = []
    with open(filename, "r") as line:
        line.readline()
        line.readline()
        for record in line:
            fields = [f.strip() for f in record.split(",")]
            if fields[0] == "B":
                bl.append(fields)
            else:
                pl.append(fields)
    book.set_book_list(bl)
    period.set_period_list(pl)
```

Here is my problem, if I call the *Book* and *Periodical* getter methods within that *read_input* method, they print just fine. But if I call those getter methods within any other method it's as if the setter method did not work and it prints None.

Is the issue that creating new instances of those subclasses is re-initializing the *self.__book_list* variable to None? That is the only thing I can think of that would be the issue but I'm not even sure that is true. Some help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Yes, a new instance of `Book` will create new atttributes for this new instance. That's the whole point of it.

Comment: This design seems very confused. You should have a `Library` object that contains list of books and a list of periodicals. `Book` and `Periodical` should be for individual items, not lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the only place you are using a setter is in the `read_input()` function (this is the only place I see it in your example), and you are calling a getter outside of this function, the issue may be that you are not returning the Book or Period after you have called `set_book_list()` on it.

It is worth mentioning that the structure seems off. Why does a book have a list of books to begin with? Maybe the controller should have a list of books, and this member should be removed from the `Book` class.